What tags are appropriate for a "reverse" reference request?
I have a just asked a question, searching for information on a reference, but I'm not sure what tags to use. I know the reference, although I know no further details about it.
A similar question searching for a digital copy of an unpublished paper by Thurston uses the "reference-request" tag which I have also used in my question.
However, I do not know if this tag is appropriate as the reference is already known. In both cases, further details are needed about the reference.
What are the appropriate tags for these questions?

The correct tag is paper-request.
